# How do I manage sprites in my J2ME games?

Tags: bitmap, java-me, sprite, lcdui

Are there any libraries for J2ME to manage bitmap sprites for games?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a game API in J2ME's MIDP 2.0 standard which has a bunch of game-centric classes, including a Sprite class. Check out this Tutorial for a good overview to using the J2ME Game API.

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/07/07/j2me3.html

Comment: Is it very memory intensive to add 50 sprites per layer with 5 layers? Is there any lighter option like maintaining an array of images and drawing them myself?

Comment: There isn't much to Layer, just bounds (4 ints) and visibility (1 boolean).  On the Sprite front, it might be a bit of overkill if it's one frame per sprite, but not if you have any sequence of animation.  I would probably isolate my resource and drawing logic and implement using the provided Sprite class.  Then if its performance was not up to snuff it wouldn't be a huge effort to write your own Sprite engine and replace it in your game.

Comment: Another note, as long as it isn't 50 unique image pieces, the Sprite class takes an Image instance as a constructor parameter.  So, you would have only one copy of each sprite image loaded for the set of sprites it represents.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [TiledLayer](http://www.j2medev.com/api/midp/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/TiledLayer.html), it gives you the option to manage and array of images in a more elegant way. Also it is less memory intensive. You just load one tiled image and the TiledLayer will do the job for you

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to manage. You can load a png image with transparency info with Image.createImage("/sprite.png");

this image can be blitted anywhere on the screen.

You could create a simple sprite class, which has the image, an x and y position, and use this.

For simple collision detection you could just compare the bounding rectangles of 2 sprites.

R